# embed sound the correct way without load delay

Tags: html, audio, embed

I've tried a bunch of options, basically described here http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_sounds.asp. But it all results in one big problem: once the page loads, it gets "frozen" for 1-2 seconds.

The freezing effect comes from embed tags (this is certain as I tried to cut the tags and everything loads fine). My sounds are very-very-very basic, sort of notifiers. There shouldn't be any problem, but still there is a problem. So... how do you embed sounds in a web page???

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly what you're trying to do. Posting code that you've tried and describing what you're trying to accomplish will help us direct you more.

But... I've found jPlayer (http://jplayer.org/) to be very helpful and easy to use for embedding sound. It's flexible and has a lot of options for customization.

Comment: that for just one sound of 17 kb !? no way

Comment: Again, posting code and explaining what you're trying to accomplish helps us help you. I don't know what you're trying to achieve, so please give me more info so I can try and help.